# Please make advanced search features for duplicate closures more discoverable

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, search, bookmarks, search-box

I was *just about* to post to ask for a search feature, but I decided to check first to make sure it isn't supported.

It is.

I had, for literally **years**, laboured under the misconception that the site does not offer a direct way to search within one's own saved bookmarks.

It does, of course. Scrolling through https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching, we eventually find the magic words buried in the middle of the page:

> `inbookmarks:mine` (or any user id) returns only questions that you (or the user whose id you entered) have bookmarked.

As the owner and frequent wielder of a dupe-hammer, this is an incredibly valuable tool. I really wish that the "vote to close -> duplicate" UI reminded me of it, or even directly included a button to add it to search terms implicitly.

Had I not reached my breaking point of frustration, it would not have occurred to me to look up the information. Established users of a site seldom have the thought that they "need help" using the site.

Further, I can't actually access the search help directly from the duplicate close UI, even though it searches the site. I am only given this info from a drop-down menu in the search at the top of the page. I rarely have occasion to use the search normally, since I am a SME in my favourite tag.

Please add such an option to the "What question is this a duplicate of?" search panel. I would prefer some actual UI buttons, since some options (like the one I'm talking about here) are clearly much more relevant than usual to duplicate-question searches, and because in this context, actual *assistance* is more valuable than documentation of all the options.

Comment: I'm not sure that this would be a very useful feature. Not everyone bookmarks common duplicate targets, so this reminder would be out of place for those users.

Comment: It is exactly what I use bookmarks for.

Comment: What *else* am I supposed to use the bookmarks for? o_O Alternately, how else am I supposed to find my common dupe targets? The general search rarely works right.

Comment: That is indeed interesting to know. So far I haven't had a use for bookmarks, but if there's such a search specifically for it...

Comment: I would also be interested in third-party scripts for this purpose, assuming such discussion is on topic on Meta.

Comment: Feel free to post a [script-request](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script-request) on Stack Apps, @KarlKnechtel - we usually discuss creation of userscripts there, and I am pretty sure such a request would be welcomed.

Comment: There are lots of uses for bookmarks. For instance, they can be used as a queue, for instance, for things to do on Stack Overflow (instead of or a supplement to external lists). The queue can be used to rate limit yourself to not burn out (for instance, *"I will do exactly one queue element per day"*). Note that bookmarks now work such that toggling one off and then on again will send it to the ***back*** of the queue (start of the list if sorted by "Added")—that wasn't the case for many many years (could be considered a bug).

Comment: *"Had I not reached my breaking point of frustration, it would not have occurred to me to look up the information"* - I can't help but think that this is the problem that should not be ignored. That moment should have come so much sooner. Still - thanks for being at a breaking point because I did not know this and the mind boggles at the uses this has.